# How many smaller muscles compose the interosseus muscle in the human hand?

Tags: human-anatomy

When looking at Wikipedia, I read that the interosseus muscle is actually composed of 3 muscles, but on the French Wikipedia, they talk about a 4th muscle.

So how many interosseus muscle components are there, 3 or 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of interosseous muscles is not constant, because of the evolutional process continuing in modern generations.

Some individuals have [4 interosseous muscles, other have three](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22009503), however there are still debates about the subject:

[image]

+

[image]